# How to incorporate a line break in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm starting to learn python, and I need to follow a series of instructions for a homework assignment. Normally, I'd be using my textbook for help, but there's problems with the shipping of my book and I don't have it yet.

Anyway, I need to figure out how to incorporate a line break here:
[image]

I need it to go from looking like that, to looking like this (the example result my professor provided):
[image]

Any help is appreciated :)

FYI I am using Python 3.4.2

Comment: put `print ('\n')` at the end of first for loop (just before second forloop is started).

Comment: Using print ('\n') where you said still gives me line breaks after each individual number.

Comment: it should not be part of for loop

Comment: you have an example in the screenshot you posted already; think a little!

Comment: @qarma I know there's an example there, my issue is I don't know how to generate what the example shows. I don't think you understand how new I am to Python and programming in general.

Comment: I'm saying you have a solution in sample code already ;-) A hint: instead of thinking of that thing as "line break", think of it as "end of line."

Comment: @qarma I know I have the solution there, but for my assignment I need to provide the function that gets you that solution. I see what you're saying, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Put another `print()` between the loops.

Comment: That still puts a line break between each individual number. I need a line break between the two sequences.

Comment: @Brian, you're wrong -- you're thinking of having a `print()` **within** a loop (indented like the loop body), but this excellent answer says **between** the loops (thus indented just like the one you have, which aligns with the `for` keywords) and as such it will work perfectly.

Comment: @AlexMartelli, Like I said, I'm just starting to learn python. I didn't register the words "between the loops" meaning no indentation. The example michaelpri provided was helpful, however I see what you mean that it leaves an unnecessary empty line. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To create a line break in Python you can use `"\n"`. This creates a newline.

For your code, you can do this:

```
def sequences():
    for i in range(27,37):
        print(i, end=" ")
    print("\n")
    for j in range(21,71,7):
        print(j, end=" ")
```

Make sure you don't indent the `"\n"` in the first for loop.

As Alex Martelli mentioned in his comment below, this adds a full line in between the two other lines. If you want to avoid this, use `print()` instead of `print("\n")`.

Comment: Thank you for being specific! I didn't know I needed to not indent where you specified. It worked :)

Comment: This leaves an empty line, not just a like break as specified, so it does **not** satisfy the conditions as posed.